# How do I get the value of drop down list on page load with jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, onload

Using jQuery, how can I get the selected item's value in a select when the page loads?
I can do it onChange etc but cant figure out the way on page load.

Here's my code:

```
<select name="symb" id="symb">
  <option value="1#10#6">Basic Personal</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2#20#6">Basic Family</option>
  <option value="7#90#12">Advanced Personal</option>
  <option value="8#120#12">Advanced Family</option>
  <option value="9#130#12">Optimum Personal</option>
  <option value="10#170#12">Optimum Family</option>
</select>
```

This is the script I'm using for getting the option value onchange:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#symb").change(function() {
          var val = $(this).symbCost(0);
    })

   $.fn.symbCost = function(pos) {
        var total = parseInt($("option:selected").val().split('#')[pos]);
        return total;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#symb").val());
});
```

Comment: I hate it when the solution is sooo easy! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/YXbDd/3/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/YXbDd/4/

API: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ `> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully` loaded.

I am not sure what `pos` context is in your case but this should do the stick.

`$("#symb").val().split('#')[0]`

Rest as demo and code, hope it helps,

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("when the page load ==> " + $("#symb").val().split('#')[0]);
    $("#symb").change(function() {
          var val = $(this).symbCost(0);
    })

   $.fn.symbCost = function(pos) {
        var total = parseInt($("option:selected").val().split('#')[pos]);
        alert(total);
        return total;
    }
});​
```

**or**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("when the page load ==> " + $("#symb option:selected").val().split('#')[0]);
    $("#symb").change(function() {
          var val = $(this).symbCost(0);
    })

   $.fn.symbCost = function(pos) {
        var total = parseInt($("option:selected").val().split('#')[pos]);
        alert(total);
        return total;
    }
});​
```

Comment: `option:selected` can be omitted too. You can just use `$("#symb").val()`

Comment: @Tats_innit: Both answers are correct, had to give the vote to the quickest one though. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @bikey77 no worries, man `:)` yes please give it to the guy above! have a nice one

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#dropdownid").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution and siple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fn.symbCost = function(pos) {
var total = parseInt($(this).val().split('#')[pos]);
    return total;
}   
$("#symb").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).symbCost(0);
}).triggerHandler('change');
```

});

Or this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fn.symbCost = function(pos) {
    var total = parseInt($(this).val().split('#')[pos]);
    return total;
}
$("#symb").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).symbCost(0);
}).symbCost(0);
```

});